# how set a fixed por in pgadmin4 because he open rand

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

It's possible to fix a port in pgAdmin4? everty time I restar my mac he open in a random port. I look in google and don't find anything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run pgAdmin4 on fixed port use python-wheel package which allows you to configure the port.

Please refer: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/

Comment: so If my chrome close, How can I list the port that pgadmin 4(mac) running?

Comment: by default it runs on 5050.